# Does tensorflow-quantum support GPU, and if so how do I make it use mine?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-quantum

I am getting started on using `tensorflow-quantum` for some QML circuit simulations. I have everything configured correctly for TensorFlow with GPU, and when I run `print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))`, it reports the presence of my GPU.

However, I've done some Googling, and I've come across a few things suggesting that `tensorflow-quantum` doesn't actually support GPU acceleration for simulations (e.g. MichaelBroughton's first reply [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/quantum/issues/193), and [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/quantum/issues/599) which is still open). However, it's unclear to me how up-to-date this state of affairs is. I can't find anything about adding GPU support in the version notes.

Does `tensorflow-quantum` currently support GPU? If so, how do I (a) make it use my GPU for simulations and (b) verify that it is doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find specific GPU support on TF Quantum, but [Pennylane](https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_qnn_module_tf) works with both Keras and Nvidia CuQuantum. It might be worth a look

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow-quantum is built upon `tensorflow==2.7.0` which does not support CUDA device (see this issue [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/52988))